# How do I create a button that simply redirects without submitting my form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, cancellation, button-to

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I want to add a “Cancel” button on my form that will simply direct the user to another part of the application.  So I implemented

```
<%= button_to "Cancel", {:controller => :my_objects, :action => 'index' }, :class => 'btn' %>
```

but this renders as a submit button and the form that this button appears in gets submitted when it is clicked, which is not what I want.  How do I change the above so that the button is just rendered as a button that directs the user somewhere else (without form submission)?

Comment: add :method => :get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a `link_to` instead.

`<%= link_to "Cancel", { controller: "my_objects", action: "index", class: "btn" } %>`